# Condition in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have `SELECT` query below:

```
select * from table t
    Where t.policy_date = @var1 and t.insurer_id = @var2
```

Here `@var1` could by empty and `@var2` also could be empty. If `@var1` is empty condition must be only `t.insurer_id = @var2`. if `@var2` is empty condition must be `t.policy_date = @var1`. Or they can be both empty and both not empty.

'@var1' and '@var2' are parametrs in procedure that i will give.

Question: How to create query that satisfy my conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
select * from table t
  Where (@var1 IS NULL OR t.policy_date = @var1) and (var2 IS NULL OR t.insurer_id = @var2)
```

when `@var` is null the first part of the where clause became `true` so we have just the second part to evaluate, and vice versa.

**Note:** If you mean `''` by "empty", use `@var = ''` instead of `@var IS NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table t
where (@var1 is null or t.policy_date = @var1)
  and (@var2 is null or t.insurer_id = @var2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.policy_date = COALESCE(@var1, t.policy_date)
AND t.insurer_id = COALESCE(@var2, t.insurer_id)
```